# Susy grid with webpack and sass-loader

Tags: node.js, webpack, susy, susy-sass, sass-loader

I'm pretty new to Node and i'm trying to use Susy grid but get this error

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./scss/waterbottle.scss
Module build failed: 
    @include gallery(1 of 2);
            ^
      No mixin named gallery
```

I installed Susy and sass-loader with this command

```
npm install sass-loader --save-dev
```

and imported Susy in my .scss file like this

```
@import "~susy/sass/susy";
```

I've tried changing this path with no luck. I shouldn't have to do that according to [their website](https://www.npmjs.com/package/susy#using-webpack).

My project file structure

[image: My project file structure]

It seems Webpack is locating the Susy file correctly, but somehow won't recognize it's mixins.

Comment: Try running npm rebuild node-sass

Comment: Hi @rjustin. It says "Testing binary Binary is fine" and the error still comes up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely installed Susy3 without reading the changelog. Susy3 no longer has a `gallery` mixin. Check the [susy3 intro and documentation](http://oddbird.net/susy/articles/) for more details. Susy2 will be maintained for the foreseeable future, if you want to stay with that.